# How to find vertices for a geometry in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geometry, pgrouting, linestring

I have a LineString, from which I need to find the vertices logically and save those vertices. Can anyone help me out?

My code is:

```
OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Geometry.Curve, { getVertices: function(nodes) {
    var vertices;
    if(nodes === true) {
        vertices = [
            this.components[0],
            this.components[this.components.length-1]
        ];
    } else if (nodes === false) {
        vertices = this.components.slice(1, this.components.length-1);
    } else {
        vertices = this.components.slice();
    }
    return vertices;
}
                }       );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the vertices by calling `getVertices()` function of `LineString` object. Assume you have a `LineString` obeject named as `line`, you can get vertices of the Line by using following code:

```
var vertices = line.getVertices();
```

The function has an optional parameter `nodes`. If it's true, only endpoints will be returned, and false, only non-endpoints will be returned. If it's not provided all vertices in the line will be returned. You can find full documentation [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/LineString-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString.getVertices).

Comment: thanks a lot, its working, but how do I get vertex by vertex.

Comment: The function returns an array, so you just iterate over vertices to get vertex one by one.